# How to split string by punctuation that ignores the period in numbers

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm using the following code in javascript to split string into phrases.

```
var result = str.match( /[^\n\.!\?\;:]+[\n\.!\?\;:]+/g );
let elements = result.map(element => element.trim());
elements = elements.filter(function (el) {return el != null && el != "";});
```

It works ok. My problem is when the string has numbers in the thousands marked with a dot that some people use like 1.500. How can alter this so that it only separates the phrases if the punctuation is followed by a space.

Comment: Try `/(?:[^\n.!?;:]|(?:[\n.!?;:](?!\s)))+[\n.!?;:]+/g`

Comment: That works. Would you mind explaining the rationale.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```js
/(?:[^\n.!?;:]|[\n.!?;:](?!\s))+[\n.!?;:]+/g
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/R6Lf8D/2). The point is that you either match any char other than the punctuation of your choice, or a punctuation not followed with a whitespace, one or more times, and then one or more punctuation symbols of your choice.

**Details**:

- `(?:` - start of a non-capturing group:

  - `[^\n.!?;:]` - any char but a newline, `.`, `!`, `?`, `;` or `:`
- `|` - or

  - `[\n.!?;:](?!\s)` - a newline, `.`, `!`, `?`, `;` or `:` not followed with a whitespace
- `)+` - one or more times
- `[\n.!?;:]+` - one or more newline, `.`, `!`, `?`, `;` or `:` chars.

See a JavaScript demo:

```js
var s = 'It works ok. My problem is when the string has numbers in the thousands marked with a dot that some people use like 1.500. How can alter this so that it only separates the phrases if the punctuation is followed by a space.';
var rx = /(?:[^\n.!?;:]|[\n.!?;:](?!\s))+[\n.!?;:]+/g;
console.log( s.match(rx) );
```